# Adding a row between query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have access to our training systems database and I currently pull a result that incorporates three tables, one being the users unique data, the results of each test attempt per user, and the actual test unique data.

A user may have three failed attempts and one completed attempt. Each attempt has its own row and a column with the date attempted and date completed. I was hoping that I could sort by the test and then users payroll number. Then inserting a row when the test string and payroll string change which would determine the last attempt that user made for that particular test.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want a update trigger or force updates via a Stored Proc that does the check. What Database is this for?

Comment: I'm not looking to update or modify the database. It's not my database. I mainly just want an easy way to identify when there's a change in either the user number or test name.

Comment: By change do you mean comparing one row to another in a result set? easily done but you need to let us know what the DB is since some DB makes this easier.

Comment: Hey Conrad, I don't actually know which database it is. It's SQL if that helps. And that's exactly what I'm looking to do.

Comment: If by SQL you mean SQL Server try `SELECT @@VERSION ` to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that has to be done in real time?  I guess not but would like to confirm it.

If you are generating some kind of report that ships out daily/weekly, it might be better to just have a batch job that maintains an aggregate table for all users in your system.

Basically store the completed, failed and passed stats by userid in a table and then run the job daily to process any new records.  This is the old fashioned way of doing it and I think it suffices in most situations.

I hope this helps.